# How to to write out a random name?

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I've 8 names in my file and every single row has only one name.

I'm trying to write out one of the names at random. I've written some codes but I do not know how I'll continue.(I'm trying to solve that problem without using array because we did not learn yet).
My list has those names;

```
patrica
natascha
lena
sara
rosa
kate
funny
ying
```

And I want to write out with `system.out.println` only one name at random

Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader inputCurrent = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aText.txt"));

    String str;
    int rowcounter =0;
    int mixNum =0;
    String strMixNum=null;
    while((str = inputCurrent.readLine())!= null){
        rowcounter++; 
        mixNum = rnd.nextInt(rowcounter)+1;
        //strMixNum = ""+strMixNum;

        String str2;
        while((str2 = inputCurrent.readLine())!= null){
            // i dont know what i s shall write here
            System.out.println(str2);
        }
    }

    inputCurrent.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't learned about arrays or lists yet, you figure out which number word you want up front, and stop reading the file when you get there.

So, if you know you have 8 words, you do this:

```
int wordToGet = rnd.nextInt(8); // returns 0-7
while ((str = inputCurrent.readLine()) != null) {
    if (wordToGet == 0)
        break; // found word
    wordToGet--;
}
System.out.println(str); // prints null if file didn't have enough words
```

Once you learn the tricks of Java, you can collapse that code, though it becomes less clear for readers, so you probably shouldn't do it this way:

```
int wordToGet = rnd.nextInt(8);
while ((str = inputCurrent.readLine()) != null && wordToGet-- > 0);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Very nice, i like the comments.

Comment: @LenaMonikaMarshall there's no way of doing that directly. You'll have to run over the file and count the lines. Your best try would be to leave the process of reading and counting to `java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines` though that's a bit beyond your level, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply read all the names, store them in a list and then pick an index randomly:

```
List<String> names = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("aText.txt"));
// pick a name randomly:
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(names.size());
String randomName = names.get(randomIndex);
System.out.println(randomName);
```

Comment: i appreciate for your answer but i'm a beginner and i don't understand so much your code :/ what does it do List<String>?

Comment: Correct answer in general, but if OP hasn't learned arrays yet, she probably hasn't learned about collections either, so not a valid answer for level of questioner.